# Aggregate SQL query in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have the following query:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_GroupInvoices 
    SELECT tbl_Invoices.CustomerName AS CustomerName, 
           tbl_Invoices.CountryCode AS CountryCode, 
           tbl_Invoices.[Group] AS [Group], 
           SUM((tbl_Invoices.PageReferenceVolume / tbl_Invoices.DaysInMonth) * tbl_Invoices.ActiveDaysInMonth) AS PageReferenceVolume, 
           SUM(tbl_Invoices.BlackPages + tbl_Invoices.ColorPages) AS ActualPageVolume, 
           ActualPageVolume / PageReferenceVolume AS UsageRate 
    FROM tbl_Invoices 
    GROUP BY tbl_Invoices.CustomerName, tbl_Invoices.CountryCode, tbl_Invoices.[Group]
```

This is working perfectly fine when I execute it directly in Ms Access 2013.
but when embedded in my VB.net code I have an error message saying:

Your query does not include the specified expression
'ActualPageVolume/PageReferenceVolume' as part of an aggregate function.

Here is my vb code

```vb
cmd.Connection = mdlLocalAccDB.accessConn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Try
   sQuery = String.Empty
   sQuery = sQuery & "INSERT INTO tbl_GroupInvoices "
   sQuery = sQuery & "SELECT tbl_Invoices.CustomerName AS CustomerName, "
   sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Invoices.CountryCode AS CountryCode, "
   sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Invoices.[Group] AS [Group], "
   sQuery = sQuery & "SUM((tbl_Invoices.PageReferenceVolume / tbl_Invoices.DaysInMonth) * tbl_Invoices.ActiveDaysInMonth) AS PageReferenceVolume, "
   sQuery = sQuery & "SUM(tbl_Invoices.BlackPages + tbl_Invoices.ColorPages) AS ActualPageVolume, "
   sQuery = sQuery & "ActualPageVolume / PageReferenceVolume AS UsageRate "
   sQuery = sQuery & "FROM tbl_Invoices "
   sQuery = sQuery & "GROUP BY tbl_Invoices.CustomerName, tbl_Invoices.CountryCode, tbl_Invoices.[Group] "
   cmd.CommandText = sQuery
   QueryReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("PrepareInvoicing: Invoicing step 6" & vbCrLf & ErrorToString())
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Any ideas ? (except it would be better to use parameters instead of string concatenations.

Comment: Since this is an insert try removing the AS PageReferenceVolume and the AS ActualPageVolume because they shouldn't be necessary anyway. If it doesn't fix the issue it may at least give you a better clue to what the error is.

Comment: Oh just read @sstan comment and I think he is right. I didn't catch that when I first read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, in SQL, you can't refer to column aliases in other parts of the same `select` clause where they are defined.  I'm surprised that Access supports that when running queries directly.

This would be the more usual way of running that query (I just replaced `ActualPageVolume / PageReferenceVolume` with their corresponding expressions):

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_GroupInvoices 
    SELECT tbl_Invoices.CustomerName AS CustomerName, 
           tbl_Invoices.CountryCode AS CountryCode, 
           tbl_Invoices.[Group] AS [Group], 
           SUM((tbl_Invoices.PageReferenceVolume / tbl_Invoices.DaysInMonth) * tbl_Invoices.ActiveDaysInMonth) AS PageReferenceVolume, 
           SUM(tbl_Invoices.BlackPages + tbl_Invoices.ColorPages) AS ActualPageVolume, 
           SUM(tbl_Invoices.BlackPages + tbl_Invoices.ColorPages) / SUM((tbl_Invoices.PageReferenceVolume / tbl_Invoices.DaysInMonth) * tbl_Invoices.ActiveDaysInMonth) AS UsageRate 
    FROM tbl_Invoices 
    GROUP BY tbl_Invoices.CustomerName, tbl_Invoices.CountryCode, tbl_Invoices.[Group]
```

Hopefully that works better.

And concerning your little note at the end:

> except it would be better to use parameters instead of string concatenations

Your current query doesn't have anything that requires parameter binding. The way you have it now is perfectly ok.

Comment: MS Access Jet/ACE SQL dialect can indeed reference calculated columns in same query. However, I cannot replicate OP's issue. I tried with ADO and DAO on an .mdb/.accdb version for both `SELECT` and `INSERT` statement. I could successfully reference named calculated columns in an aggregate query. @L.Moronvalle - what is your Driver/Provider? Version?

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0